# why is python coverage saying lines were missed?

Tags: django, coverage.py, python-coverage

I'm trying to use coverage with Django, but I seem to be getting incorrect results.  My app is named "stats" and I have this test:

```
class ListSchoolsTest(TestCase):
    def test_initial_list(self):
        self.client.login(username='skeezy', password='skeezy')
        resp = self.client.get("/stats/list_schools/")
        self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
```

On the command line, I run:

```
coverage run --source="." manage.py test stats
```

And the test passes.  All my views are currently in stats/views.py

But when I run "coverage report", I get this line:

```
Name                 Stmts   Miss  Cover
----------------------------------------
<snip>
stats/views            110    110     0%
```

Any idea what I am (not) doing that would cause coverage to report all lines missed in stats/views.py, even though it would have to be hit in order for the test to pass?   (just as a belt-and-suspenders, I put a print statement in my view, and it's definitely getting hit.)

Comment: I'm having the same problem. In Windows the coverage works correctly, but when I send to Travis all statements not in the test itself are missed.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you have pip installed your app without the `-e` flag? Then the modules are not imported from your project directory but the path they were installed to and coverage thinks those are different files.